# Represent class and properties with RDFS

Tags: xml, rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

I want to represent this with RDFS:
- A book has a title and an author
- An author has a name

I tried this:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >

    <rdf:Description rdf:ID="Book"> 
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/…/rdf-schema#Class"/> 
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Property rdf:ID="titleBook"> 
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Book"/> 
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="xmlns:rdfsLiteral"/>
    </rdf:Property>

    <rdf:Property rdf:ID="authorBook"> 
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Book"/> 
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Author"/>
    </rdf:Property>

    <rdf:Description rdf:ID="Author"> 
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/…/rdf-schema#Class"/> 
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Property rdf:ID="nameAuthor"> 
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Author"/> 
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="xmlns:rdfsLiteral"/>
    </rdf:Property>
```

But I'm not sure, I'm confused between domain and range.
How to represent that a book contains an author (a class in a class) with RDFS ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'm not sure, I'm confused between domain and range.

When a property p has a domain D, it means that whenever you have a triple

```
x p y
```

then x is an instance of D. When a property p has a range R, it means that whenever you have a triple

```
x p y
```

then y is an instance of R.  For instance, if you have:

```
ex:hasTitle rdfs:domain ex:Book
```

then from

```
:dickens1859 ex:hasTitle "A Tale of Two Cities"@en
```

you can *infer* that:

```
:dickens1859 rdf:type ex:Book
```

> How to represent that a book contains an author (a class in a class)
>   with RDFS ?

Classes in RDFS are not the same as classes in an object oriented programming language.  Classes are much more like sets in set theory.  In RDFS, you can declare Book and Author classes, and declare a hasAuthor property with domain Book and range Author:

```
ex:Book a rdfs:Class .
ex:Author a rdfs:Class .
ex:hasAuthor rdfs:domain ex:Book ;
             rdfs:range ex:Author .
```

If you want to say that every instance of Book has at least one author, you'd need to use a more powerful language than RDFS.  For instance, you can use OWL, where you can say that "every book has an author" (that is, "at least one author") with an axiom like:

> Book ⊑ ∃ hasAuthor.Author

Comment: Thank you, I better understand.
I used object oriented programming language, so this is new to me.
But can you tell me, how write your example in RDF/XML, like I tried ?

Comment: @Jéjé I wrote it in [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/), a standard RDF serialization language.  It's the easiest one to write by hand, and I'd recommend that you become comfortable working with it.  You can convert with most libraries, or a website like [EasyRDF Converter](http://www.easyrdf.org/converter).  In this case, you'd get [output like this](http://pastebin.com/ZQPdE4Mu).

Comment: Ok thanks, nice tool! Sorry to annoy you again, but what do you think about my modeling (http://pastebin.com/DRxuWNn2), it seems correct to you?

Comment: And why we use "rdf:Description" to define Properties and not "rdf:Property", is it the same?

Comment: I didn't explicitly add `hasAuthor rdf:type rdf:Property` triples, but if you did, you might see rdf:Property elements in the RDF/XML.

Comment: OK. So I added to all: http://pastebin.com/N0Xmv02A . I hope that is correct now... Have you some examples of instances creation?
How can I create an instance of Book for example?

Comment: That's not right. In `<rdf:type rdf:resource="rdf:Property"/>`  the value of the rdf:resource attribute needs to be a URI, but you've given it the string `"rdf:Property"`.  There's not shortage of RDF out there to look at.  Try finding some legal samples and running them through converters if you need to see different formats.